# Is there a way to send the message of an e-mailing as an E-mail?

Tags: civimail, email

We sent a mass mailing and afterwards needed to individually send again the message (template created with Mosaico) as a single E-mail. Apart from copy-pasting HTML code or creating a new recepients group or copy the sent mailing and send it as a test to the target recipient, is there a way to do so?
I've tried the mosaico messages template but it's not exactly my purpose.
Any experience?

Comment: depends why the individual missed out - should they have been in the original group? if so you could resend to the corrected 'original group' and exclude the recipients of the original mailing. should result in just going to that one extra person

Comment: Agree with Pete. Or just put that person in their own group temporarily and click the "re-use" action link for the sent mailing and send to that temporary group.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. For example somebody can say 'please write instead to my other address I'm giving you now because I'm facing troubles to access it' and you just want to send single messages. I know we can use groups, I was looking for something quicker.